# Get a response from the resource with token using sp_OACreate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a response from a resource in the form of a JSON, but I get in response that no token was passed. Checked through Postman there I get the answer. What am I doing wrong?

```
 declare
 @method varchar(5) = 'GET',
    @url varchar(8000) = 'http://srvweb1c/AccountingCorp/hs/api_accounting_corp/agent_info/',
    @token NVARCHAR(2000) = '567f9bbc-fc08-4dd1-b64b-e4289b221383',
    @params NVARCHAR(2000) = ''

DECLARE @authHeader NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @contentType NVARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @postData NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @responseText NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @responseXML NVARCHAR(2000);

DECLARE @ret INT;
DECLARE @status NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @statusText NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @internalToken INT;

SET @authHeader= 'Bearer ' + @token;
SET @contentType = 'application/json';

-- Open the connection.
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @internalToken OUT;

-- Send the request.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @internalToken, 'open', NULL, @method, @url, 'false';
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @internalToken, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @authHeader; 
if @ret <> 0 
      begin 
            set @ret = 'sp_OAMethod setRequestHeader failed' 
      end
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @internalToken, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @internalToken, 'send', NULL, @params;

-- Handle the response.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @internalToken, 'status', @status OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @internalToken, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @internalToken, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;

-- Show the response.
PRINT 'Status: ' + @status + ' (' + @statusText + ')';
PRINT 'Response text: ' + @responseText;

-- Close the connection.
EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @internalToken;
```

Comment: The first thing you're doing wrong is using the sp_OA* methods. Those typically aren't thread-safe, they leak resources like a sieve and reduce SQL Server reliability. Web service client processes should be running external to SQL Server in your favorite general purpose programming language: e.g.: C#, PowerShell or Java (if you must).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how the token is transferred:

```
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @internalToken, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'token', @Token;
```